# import fails for murmur2 package in Redshift UDF

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions, murmurhash

I am trying to import murmur2 package as a library in Redshift database. I did following steps

1. Run the module packer
   `$ ./installPipModuleAsRedshiftLibrary.sh -m murmur2 -s s3://path/to/murmur2/lib`
2. Create library on redshift
   `CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY murmur2    LANGUAGE plpythonu    from 's3://path/to/murmur2/lib/murmur2.zip'    WITH CREDENTIALS AS 'aws_access_key_id=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;aws_secret_access_key=SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS' region 'us-east-1';`
3. Create function and query

   `create OR REPLACE function f_py_kafka_partitioner (s varchar, ps int)

   returns int     stable      as $$      import murmur2

   m2 = murmur2.murmur64a(s, len(s), 0x9747b28c)

   return m2 % ps

   $$ language plpythonu;`

`SELECT f_py_kafka_partitioner('jiimit', 100);`

**This gives following error :**

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: ImportError: No module named murmur2. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  ImportError: No module named murmur2. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information
  code:      10000
  context:   UDF
  query:     0
  location:  udf_client.cpp:366
  process:   padbmaster [pid=31381]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

And here is the contents of svl_udf_log

```
0   ImportError: No module named murmur2 2018-10-14 07:05:43.431561 line 2, in f_py_kafka_partitioner\n  f_py_kafka_partitioner  1000 20000 0
```

Folder structure looks like this
[image: Murmur2 Directory tree]

Comment: And have you looked at what is recorded in svl_udf_log?

Comment: @Nathan there is also the same thing, updated the content of svl_udf_log.

Comment: Does your zip file have the correct file and folder structure as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html#udf-importing-custom-python-library-modules ?

Comment: Nope it is but different, maybe because it is written in C with a python wrapper, added the folder structure in question.